# How to combine str and int variables?

Tags: python

For this problem, I need to "separate" or identify individual sets of 3 different user inputs: a name, an address, and a salary. Then the program needs to find the highest salary and print the name and the address of the person that it belongs to.

I'm not sure how I can do this in Python.

I know I can use max(salary) but how can I print the associated name and address?

I'm trying to do this using a while loop.
Edit:
Ok, so I'm a beginner so I apologize if this is too basic. 
This is what I came up with so far.

```
name = str(raw_input("Input name: "))
address = str(raw_input("Input address: "))
salary = int(raw_input("Input salary or a number < 0 to end program: "))
x = []
while salary > 0: 
    name = str(raw_input("Input name: "))
    address = str(raw_input("Input address: "))
    salary = int(raw_input("Input salary or a number < 0 to end program: "))
x.append(salary) #this returns error: 'int' object is not iterable
m = max(salary)
print #should print name, address associated with max(salary)
```

Thank you

Comment: Paste the code you tried please.

Comment: Please give a sample input, the desired output and show us some code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: You need to provide more context. You can read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to see how to write an answerable question.

Comment: we do not  even mind doing the job for you. please provide a sample of the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
max_salary = None
max_index = None
salary = 1
index = 0
x = []
while salary > 0:
    name = raw_input("Input name: ")
    address = raw_input("Input address: ")
    salary = int(raw_input("Input salary or a number < 0 to end program: "))
    if max_salary is None or salary > max_salary:
        max_salary = salary
        max_index = index
    index += 1
    x.append("{}  {}  {}".format(name, address, salary))

if max_index  is not None:
    print(x[max_index])
```

---

Another way (preferred):

```
x = []
while True:
    name = raw_input("Input name: ")
    address = raw_input("Input address: ")
    salary = int(raw_input("Input salary or a number < 0 to end program: "))
    if salary < 0:
        break
    x.append((name, address, salary))

if x:
    print("{}  {}  {}".format(*max(x, key=lambda t: t[2])))
```

Comment: Thanks! But the problem I am having really is how to identify the highest salary and the name and address of the person that has said salary since even if the program can identify the highest salary, it is the address and the name that have to be printed. Should I be treating name, address, salary as a single input? How can I do this?

Comment: @Martin Ah! so your issue is not combining stings and integers in a single print statement as I thought you have described the issue in the question.

Comment: You are nearly there, use a dict  to store  the raw_input . Then append the dictionary in the empty list that you  would have created at the beginning . Now you have  a list  of dictionary. Iterate through the dictionary  and use  max and itemgetter or something to get the  highest salary  then return the dict number. All you dict would be indexed in the list

Comment: @Martin make sure you embed  the whole in a loop. So you can ask, at the beginning of your programme something like. how many people  you wan to enter. And take ta number to create the elements of your in while or for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This should  be working fine.

```
people=[]

elements= int(input('enter the number of people you want: '))

 for i in range(elements):
     name= input('enter the name of person %d: '% (i+1))
     address= input('enter the address: ')
     salary= int(input('enter the salary: '))
     person={}
     person['name']=name
     person['address']= address
     person['salary']= salary
     people.append(person)

# getting the max from all the salaries and the max
sal_max= max([x['salary'] for x in people])


 # matching the max salary:
for i in people:
    if i['salary']==sal_max:
    print (i['name'], i['address'])
```

Comment: @Martin. This should be  what you are  looking for ... You can improve and modify the codes if you want